# Unknown class in Compiled Swift Framework embedded in Objective-C Project

Tags: objective-c, swift, frameworks

I have a framework binary built with Swift that I'm trying to incorporate into an Objective-C project. However the class in the framework isn't available.

In the swift framework, the class is defined like this:

```
@objcMembers
@objc public final class Messaging: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, LogsManagerDelegate {
...
}
```

I drag the archived and exported framework directly into the project to use and make sure the Defines Module is set to Yes in the Build Settings.

In the Objective-C I try to use the framework:

```
@import ContactAtOnceMessaging;

@implementation MessagingExperience
Messaging *messaging;    // Unknown type name 'Messaging'

...

@end
```

If I drag the code for the framework directly into the project, Messaging is a known class so I know the Swift is okay.

I also tried changing the import to the following, but that didn't work.

```
#import "ContactAtOnceMessaging/ContactAtOnceMessaging-Swift.h"
```

I also tried using CocoaPods to import the framework and that hasn't helped.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ^ Useless, I know. Anyway, we mostly use cocoapods to help manage this stuff. I'm guessing that you're missing some kind of umbrella header or module map or one of these fancy things that cocoapods does for you.

Comment: I tried using CocoaPods too and it didn't work . Wish I could avoid the Objective-C, but the framework has to work with developers still using it.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that I experienced the same problem as you. I was also able to resolve it. I'm not sure if the original problem was caused by an anomaly somewhere in my configuration. I did, however, test the following procedure and found it to work reliably with Xcode 9.3.

---

I first made a test Swift framework named `Dynamic-Framework-Tester`, in an Xcode project, and set it to be copied to an absolute path on every build.

I then performed the following steps to setup my Objective-C project:

1. Made a new project with Objective-C as the language.
2. Dragged the framework from its absolute path into the project **without** choosing "Copy items if needed".
3. Deleted the framework from **Linked Frameworks and Libraries** because it will get added automatically in step (4).
4. Added the framework to **Embedded Binaries**.
5. In build settings, set **Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries** to Yes.
6. Added my custom framework path to the **Framework Search Paths** setting in the build settings.

---

In the Objective-C project, I imported the framework using

```
@import Dynamic_Framework_Tester;
```

and called a method exposed in the framework from Objective-C.

Using a simulator, I was able to update the framework and have the changes applied on subsequent runs of the app.